# i want to select documents which has duplicate array elements with same name and Id in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

```
{
"name" : "abc", </br>  
"id":"123456",   
"skills":[        
            {       
              "skill_id" :"SK01",     
              "skill_name" : "Java",    
              "level" : "expert"     
            },    
            {     
              "skill_id" :"SK01",   
              "skill_name" : "Java",   
              "level" : "intermediate"    
            },    
           {   
              {    
              "skill_id" :"SK02",   
              "skill_name" : "c++",   
              "level" : "intermediate"   
            },   
           }   
         ]   
}, 

{   
"name" : "cde",  
"id":"554432",   
"skills":[   
            {   
              "skill_id" :"SK01",   
              "skill_name" : "Java",  
              "level" : "expert"   
            },   
            {   
              "skill_id" :"SK02",   
              "skill_name" : "c++",   
              "level" : "intermediate"   
            },   
              
              {    
              "skill_id" :"SK02",
              "skill_name" : "c++",  
              "level" : "intermediate"   
            },   
           }   
         ]   
}, 

{  
"name" : "cdef",   
"id":"6789076",   
"skills":[   
            {   
              "skill_id" :"SK01",   
              "skill_name" : "Java",  
              "level" : "expert"   
            },   
            {  
              "skill_id" :"SK02",   
              "skill_name" : "c++",  
              "level" : "intermediate"   
            },  
           {   
              {   
              "skill_id" :"SK03",   
              "skill_name" : "php",  
              "level" : "intermediate"   
            },  
           }   
         ]   
}
```

i want to filter out ids which having duplicate skill_id and skill_name as array elements.

want to get output -> which having array elements with duplicate skill_id and skill_name

```
123456,6789076
```

can somebody please help me with this couchbase query?

Comment: Please edit your question and format the json code.

Answer (score 0):

As A. Najafi pointed out your Json is lacking I can only assume you meant (*I had to do make several fixes if you want you can pretty-print it via https://beautifier.io/*):

```
{ "name": "abc", "id": "123456", "skills": [{ "skill_id": "SK01", "skill_name": "Java", "level": "expert" }, { "skill_id": "SK01", "skill_name": "Java", "level": "intermediate" }, { "skill_id": "SK02", "skill_name": "c++", "level": "intermediate" } ] } 
{ "name": "cde", "id": "554432", "skills": [{ "skill_id": "SK01", "skill_name": "Java", "level": "expert" }, { "skill_id": "SK02", "skill_name": "c++", "level": "intermediate" }, { "skill_id": "SK02", "skill_name": "c++", "level": "intermediate" } ] }
{ "name": "cdef", "id": "6789076", "skills": [{ "skill_id": "SK01", "skill_name": "Java", "level": "expert" }, { "skill_id": "SK02", "skill_name": "c++", "level": "intermediate" }, { "skill_id": "SK03", "skill_name": "php", "level": "intermediate" } ] }
```

Now applying a Query (*not very elegant but it works*)

```
SELECT cnt,
       id,
       idname
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,
           MAX(c.id) AS id,
           c.idname AS idname
    FROM (
        SELECT b.id,
               b.id || '@' || b.skill_id || '@' || b.skill_name AS idname,
               b.skill_id AS skill_id,
               b.skill_name AS skill_name
        FROM (
            SELECT a.id,
                   [u.skill_name,u][1].*
            FROM test AS a
            UNNEST skills AS u ) AS b ) AS c
    GROUP BY idname ) AS d
WHERE cnt = 1
```

You can find filter out the offending id's (*wrap with another SELECT if you want only the id*)

```
[
  {
    "cnt": 1,
    "id": "123456",
    "idname": "123456@SK02@c++"
  },
  {
    "cnt": 1,
    "id": "554432",
    "idname": "554432@SK01@Java"
  },
  {
    "cnt": 1,
    "id": "6789076",
    "idname": "6789076@SK01@Java"
  },
  {
    "cnt": 1,
    "id": "6789076",
    "idname": "6789076@SK02@c++"
  },
  {
    "cnt": 1,
    "id": "6789076",
    "idname": "6789076@SK03@php"
  }
]
```

Change the where clause to "WHERE cnt > 1" and find the errors.

```
[
  {
    "cnt": 2,
    "id": "554432",
    "idname": "554432@SK02@c++"
  },
  {
    "cnt": 2,
    "id": "123456",
    "idname": "123456@SK01@Java"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO default VALUES("f01", { "name": "abc", "id": "123456", "skills": [{ "skill_id": "SK01", "skill_name": "Java", "level": "expert" }, { "skill_id": "SK01", "skill_name": "Java", "level": "intermediate" }, { "skill_id": "SK02", "skill_name": "c++", "level": "intermediate" } ] } );
INSERT INTO default VALUES("f02", { "name": "cde", "id": "554432", "skills": [{ "skill_id": "SK01", "skill_name": "Java", "level": "expert" }, { "skill_id": "SK02", "skill_name": "c++", "level": "intermediate" }, { "skill_id": "SK02", "skill_name": "c++", "level": "intermediate" } ] });
INSERT INTO default VALUES("f03",{ "name": "cdef", "id": "6789076", "skills": [{ "skill_id": "SK01", "skill_name": "Java", "level": "expert" }, { "skill_id": "SK02", "skill_name": "c++", "level": "intermediate" }, { "skill_id": "SK03", "skill_name": "php", "level": "intermediate" } ] });

SELECT RAW a.id
FROM default AS a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT RAW 1 FROM a.skills AS s
              GROUP BY s.skill_name, s.skill_id
              HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
              LIMIT 1);
```

If you need id, ARRAY of duplicate skill_name, skill_id, count

```
SELECT a.id, nskills AS skills
FROM default AS a
LET nskills = (SELECT s.skill_name, s.skill_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt
               FROM a.skills AS s
               GROUP BY s.skill_name, s.skill_id
               HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
              )
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(nskills) > 0;
```